# ReactJS giving error Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using ReactJS.

When I run the code below the browser says:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined**

Any hints at all as to what is wrong would be appreciated.

First the line used to compile the code:

```
browserify -t reactify -t babelify examples/temp.jsx  -o examples/public/app.js
```

And the code:

```
var React = require('react');

class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello </div>;
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
After burning in hellfire for three days on this problem I found that I was not using the latest version of react.

**Install globally:**

```
sudo npm install -g react@0.13.2
```

**install locally:**

```
npm install react@0.13.2
```

**make sure the browser is using the right version too:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="react-0.13.2.js"></script>
```

Hope this saves someone else three days of precious life.

Comment: As of 0.14.8, you can still get this if you do something like `extends React.component` (lowercase `c`).

Comment: @Kevin just want to rephrase , basically If you have a typo there somewhere , in my case it was `Components` instead of `Component`  :). Your comment helped BTW

Comment: My issue was I wasn't exporting the class at the end of the file ...

Comment: I did React.Components (plural), the right is React.Component (singular) Ow good... how did i miss that...

Comment: Similar error may also happen when somebody writes `import Relay, { Mutation } from 'react-relay';` instead of intended `import Relay, { Mutation } from 'react-relay/classic';`

Comment: This can also happen if you have recursive imports. i.e ComponentA requires ComponentB and ComponentB requires ComponentA.

Comment: I got this error from accidentally including empty parentheses (as in a parameter-less function declaration):

`export default class SideNav extends React.Component() {...}`

Corrected to the following and all was fine: `export default class SideNav extends React.Component {...}`

Comment: Another problem is that I was referencing a class that I had after the position. Moving the extending class AFTER the class I was trying to extend fixed the issue.

Comment: @Kevin Suttle You comment is actually more useful than the answer

Comment: In my case, this error only occurs in the server (showing just a plain page) not in local. local there is no issue for me.

Comment: not applicable in the case but if you have an `index.js` and it defines B then A as exports but B extends A, then this will also throw this error as B is created before A is available either reference the actual file or ensure your index is in the order of requirements

Answer (score 368, accepted):

**Class Names**

Firstly, if you're certain that you're extending from the correctly named class, e.g. **React.Component**, not React.component or React.createComponent, you may need to upgrade your React version. See answers below for more information on the classes to extend from.

**Upgrade React**

React has only supported ES6-style classes since version 0.13.0 (see their official blog post on the support introduction [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html).

Before that, when using:

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component
```

you were attempting to use ES6 keywords (`extends`) to subclass from a class which wasn't defined using ES6 `class`. This was likely why you were running into strange behaviour with `super` definitions etc.

So, yes, **TL;DR** - update to React v0.13.x.

**Circular Dependencies**

This can also occur if you have circular import structure. One module importing another and the other way around. In this case you just need to refactor your code to avoid it. [More info](https://medium.com/content-uneditable/circular-dependencies-in-javascript-a-k-a-coding-is-not-a-rock-paper-scissors-game-9c2a9eccd4bc#.9nppw7oqv)

Comment: For everyone else that has this issue but updating React is not the fix - scroll further down to the other answers, it might be a simple typo. In my case it was a class-definition using ```React.component``` instead of ```React.Component```

Comment: FYI, old way class can be extended also with `extends`. Try this 
`var x = function(){};
class y extends x {}`

Comment: An extraordinarily annoying and non-descriptive error. Mine too was entirely down to a typo - `Componment` instead of `Component`. Moral is check your typing very, very carefully!

Comment: It was a circular import structure for me. Thanks for saving me a lot of hours of debugging!

Comment: Just FYI. I recently got the same error despite being on ReactJS 16.x. Turns out I had a typo in this line: `class App extends React.Component () {...}` - which should be corrected to `class App extends React.Component {...}`  (without the `()` at the end)

Comment: Capital 'C' Component! #facepalm

Comment: It's amazing that I end up many times in my life on this answer without remembering that I should have check the C

Comment: First line was the answer.

Comment: It was a circular dependency for me.

Comment: I was getting the same error when I try `React.Components` instead of `React.Component`, and this answer helped me.

Comment: In my case changing `Component` to `React.Component` worked. I'm using react native. Why I have to change it to `React.Component`? I'm including `import React from "react";`

Answer (score 137):

This means that you want subclass something, which should be `Class`, but is `undefined`. The reasons might be:

- typo in `Class extends ...`, so you extending undefined variable
- typo in `import ... from`, so you import `undefined` from module
- referenced module does not contain the value, you want import (e.g. obsolete module - case with React), so you importing non existing value (`undefined`)
- typo in referenced module `export ...` statement, so it exports undefined variable
- referenced module missing `export` statement at all, so it exports just `undefined`

Comment: In my case it was a lowercase of Component in React.Component.

Comment: In my case it was a self written class not correctly imported. I was importing the default exported class via `import {Foo} from 'bar'` instead of `import Foo from 'bar'`.
Upvoted therefore.

Comment: Don't do this either: `class Thing extends React.Component() {` -- I had to remove the `()`

Comment: In my case this error was caused by accidentally creating a circular reference by what I was importing(the class I wanted to extend to the subclass) in my components render function.  When I tried to execute/render the subclass since the superClass wasnt created yet it was undefined.

Comment: ^ Caused by a circular reference for me as well.

Comment: In my case, I updated a dependency from which I was extending a module, and the module name had changed. Been using React since 0.11 and they still need to work on their error messages, grumble grumble...

Comment: class Widget extends React.Compoment {

Took me far too long to figure out lol

Comment: This is an important error that signals that you're not using a JavaScript linter. In case of a faulty import or extend the linter notifies you in IDE.

Comment: In my case... it was because I was trying to import React, { Component } from 'react-native' rather than 'react'  :D  whoops.

Comment: I was extending React and not Component.  It's always something dumb, isn't it?

Answer (score 94):

It can also be caused by a typo error, so instead of `Component` with capital C, you have `component` with lower c, for example:

```
React.component //wrong.
React.Component //correct.
```

**Note:**
The source of this error is may be because there is `React` and we think automatically what comes next should be a react method or property starting with a lowercase letter, but in fact it is another **Class**(`Component`) which should start with a capital case letter.

Comment: huh, strangely this error isn't caught during the webpack build step, but it will show up at run time.

Answer (score 33):

In my case, with react-native, the error was that I had

```
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
```

instead of

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: This worked in my case!  The documentation provided in react-native site has this buggy example :)

Answer (score 20):

I've seen this error when you have a circular dependency.

```
class A extends B {}
class B extends C {}
class C extends A {}
```

Comment: I was trying to extend an imported class and then re-export that extension as the original name of the original import. So that was probably it?

Answer (score 18):

You can also receive this if you are attempting to execute `React.Component` with an erroneous `()` in your class definition.

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component() {}
                                                        ^^ REMOVE
```

Which I sometimes manage to do when I'm converting from a stateless functional component to a class.

Comment: THIS was the issue for me. very silly. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16):

I experienced this when missing an export statement for the JSX class.

For example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
}
export default MyComponent // <- add me
```

Answer (score 10):

For any other persons, that may develop this issue. You could also check that the `component` method in `React.Component` is capitalized. I had that same issue and what caused it was that I wrote:

```
class Main extends React.component {
  //class definition
}
```

I changed it to

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  //class definition
}
```

and everything worked well

Answer (score 7):

**Webpack 4 Chunks and Hashes with Uglification by TerserPlugin**

This can occur when Webpack uses chunks and hashes with minification and unglification via TerserPlugin (currently on version 1.2.3). In my case the error was narrowed down to the uglification by the Terser Plugin of my `vendors.[contenthash].js` bundle which holds my `node_modules`. Everything worked when not using hashes.

Solution was to exclude the bundle in the uglification options:

```
optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      chunkFilter: (chunk) => {
        // Exclude uglification for the `vendors` chunk
        if (chunk.name === 'vendors') {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
    }),
  ],
}
```

[More info](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#chunkfilter)

Comment: This indeed solved the problem for me, however I was able to pin point the culprit and so at the end I was able to apply the uglification. See my answer - react-dazzle.

Comment: I narrowed down to terser plugin, ultimately changing react-script to version 3.2.0 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

I am going to contribute another possible solution, one that worked for me. I was using the convenience index to collection all components into one file.

I don't believe at the time of writing this is officially supported by babel, and throws typescript into a spin - however I've seen it used in many projects and is definitely convenient.

However, when used in combination with inheritance it seems to throw the error presented in the question above.

A simple solution is, for modules that act as parents need to be imported directly instead of via a convenience index file.

**./src/components/index.js**

```
export Com1 from './com-1/Com1';
export Com2 from './com-2/Com2';
export Com3 from './com-3/Com3';
export Parent1 from './parent/Parent1';
```

**./src/components/com-1/Com1.js**

```
import { Com2, Com3 } from '../index';

// This works fine
class Com1 {        
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Com2 {...things} />
                <Com3 {...things} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**./src/components/com-3/Com3.js**

```
import { Parent } from '../index';

// This does _not_ work
class Com3 extends Parent {        
}
```

**./src/components/com-3/Com3.js**

```
import Parent from '../parent/Parent';

// This does work
class Com3 extends Parent {        
}
```

Comment: This helped me figure out what I did wrong. Accidentally wrapped the component name in { } in my import statement. Subtle difference. Can be hard to spot that mistake.

Answer (score 6):

I got this when I had a typo on my import:

```
import {Comonent} from 'react';
```

Comment: I also got this with extends React.Components instead of React.Component (no s).

Comment: I also got this but for typing small first letter of a component - ... extends React.component {}

Answer (score 5):

Check for the Classes you extend actually exists, few React methods are depreciated, It also might be a Typo error `'React.Components'` instead of `'React.Component'`

Good Luck!!

Comment: In my case I was using `React.component` instead of `React.Component` (notice the capital "C" I was missing)

Answer (score 4):

I have same issue, just change from `Navigator` to `{Navigator}`

```
import Navigator from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components'
// to
import {Navigator} from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components'
```

Comment: basically it should match like this:

`export Foo ... import { Foo }`
 -
 or
 - 
`export default Foo ... import Foo`

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

Answer (score 4):

### My conditions

- Create-React-App
- React-scripts v3.2
- [Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) rich text editor v3.1
- Development mode worked fine
- The production build was broken with the error mentioned in the question

### Solution to my problem

Downgrade Froala to v3.0.

Something in v3.1 broke our Create React App build process.

### Update: Use react scripts v3.3

We discovered that there was an issue between React Scripts 3.2 and Froala 3.1.

Updating to React Scripts v3.3 allowed us to upgrade to Froala 3.1.

Comment: I love you. I want to come to find you and kiss your feet !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! (Nightmare all-nighter over)

Comment: I'm not using create react app, but facing the same issue on prod with froala 3.1. Can you explain what was the issue here?

Comment: There's a project I have with the same issue only in production. This only happened after updating an internal library. No `create-react-app` and no `froala`. Curious what causes this issue to only occur in production. Do you know what was different?

Comment: I can't answer any of your questions. All I know is that under the conditions I had, doing what I said in my answer solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with Next.js 13 and tried all the solutions above but none worked for me. I had to change the component to a client component before the error disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Not correct for this answer but for others with same error my ridiculously silly mistake could potentially help.

Stupidly,my issue was **using function notation by including () following the class name**.

Make sure your syntax is correct. And you've imported & exported any external components/modules with the correct names and paths.

This template should work fine if you have a newish version of react installed:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ExampleClass extends Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ExampleClass
```

Answer (score 2):

I`ve written

```
React.component
```

instead of `React.Component`
That was my issue))
and was looking for this more than half an hour.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using:

```
class Root extends React.Component() {
// THIS IS WORNG
// After React.Component () <- WRONG!!
}
```

which was wrong but correct is:

```
class Root extends React.Component {
// THIS IS CORRECT
// That -> '()' after React.Component was typo
}
```

also make sure there is 
√ `React.Component`
NOT 
ˣ `React.component` or `React.Components`

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems clear the OP didn't commit this mistake as they have included the correct form already in the question. Were you getting the same error as OP but with a different cause?

Comment: Yes I was getting the same error as OP but I found that the cause was different and hope this will help others.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this error while importing component like:

```
import React, { Components } from 'react';
```

instead of

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be a third party package causing this.
In our case it was [react-dazzle](https://github.com/Raathigesh/dazzle).
We have similar settings to that of @steine ([see this answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54899812/145599)).

In order to find the problematic package I ran the webpack build locally with production mode and thus was able to find the problematic package in the stack trace.
So for us [this](https://github.com/Raathigesh/dazzle/issues/53) provided the solution and I was able to keep the uglification.

Answer (score 2):

Change `import React from 'react-dom` to `import React, {Component} from 'react'`
And change `class Classname extends React.Component` to `class Classname extends Component`
If you are using the latest version of *React(16.8.6 as of now)*.

Answer (score 1):

Using Babel (5.8) I get the same error if I try to use the expression `export default` in combination with some other `export`:

```
export const foo = "foo"
export const bar = "bar"
export default function baz() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me too when I used this :

```
class App extends React.Component(){

}
```

Instead of the right one :

```
class App extends React.Component{

}
```

Notice:- () in the first one which is the main cause of this problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is one answer:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; // NOT 'react-dom'
```

Comment: exactly my typo

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I fixed this error by change `export default class yourComponent extends React.Component() {}` to `export default class yourComponent extends React.Component {}`.
Yes delete the parenthesis `()` fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

Look if you have a typo error in your importation or your class generation, it could be simply that.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error occur due to 'comments' in the bundle generated by webpack. Using 'pathinfo'= true in webpack.config.js can cause this issue:

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
  }
}
```

> 'pathinfo' defaults to true in development and false in production
>   mode. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpathinfo
>   Try setting this value to false to resolve the issue.

This can also happen if you are not using a plugin to strip the comments from the build output. Try using UglifyJs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/v/1.3.0):

webpack.config.js

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  ...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin(
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          output: {
            comments: false
          }
        }
      }),
    )],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be a spelling/case mistake in component name:
For example:

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component

class HelloMessage extends React.component
```

Please check.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting this error in a TypeScript project, which means all the spelling problems or trying to call a class constructor etc. mentioned in other answers would be caught at compile time already.

The fix I had for this problem was to not re-export the child component. The erroneous relationship I had was like

```
// src/Parent.tsx
Class Parent extends React.Component { }

// src/child/Child.tsx
export default class Child extends Parent { }

// src/child/index.ts
export { default as Child } from './Child';

// src/Caller.tsx
import {Child} from './child';

function Caller() {
  return <Child />  
}
```

It then works fine after I remove the re-export:

```
// src/Parent.tsx
Class Parent extends React.Component { }

// src/child/Child.tsx
export default class Child extends Parent { }

// src/Caller.tsx
import Child from './child/Child';

function Caller() {
  return <Child />  
}
```

Comment: This should certainly earn you the necromancer badge.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving this error and are using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) (like in a Grunt task), you might have experienced a dumb moment like I did where you unintentionally told `browserify-shim` to treat React as already part of the global namespace (for example, loaded from a CDN).

If you want Browserify to include React as part of the transform, and not a separate file, make sure the line `"react": "global:React"` does not appear in the `"browserify-shim"` section in your `packages.json` file.

Comment: How do you avoid `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react'` after removing the browserify-shim config? Basically I want to keep react as an external dependency but browserify seems to not understand how to build the bundle and keep React external. This may or may not be because the module I am including in my browserify entry point has react as a dependency.

Comment: FWIW, removing react from the browserify-shim config and letting browserify reconcile the dependency normally still results in the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you had used `require` instead of `import` within your code.

Answer (score 0):

For those using `react-native`:

```
import React, {
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
```

may produce this error.

Whereas referencing `react` directly is the more stable way to go:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was React.Element change to React.Component that make fix for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Another occurrence with Expo/react-native with typescript : sometimes when you are recompiling the typescript files in the middle of a packaging, the react packager is lost.

The only way to make my app run again is to clear the cache; if you are using the expo cli, you can press press R (that is an UPPERCASE 'R'); this will rebuild the whole bundle. Sometimes switching to development mode also helps....

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a npm module with peer dependencies. The error was caused by the wrong 'external' config in he module's webpack config:

```
  externals: {
    react: 'react',
    react: 'prop-types',
  },
```

It should be:

```
externals: {
    react: 'react',
    ['prop-types']: 'prop-types',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because my `react` and `react-dom` versions were not matching after a merge.

I fixed it by manually entering the version number I wanted and re-running `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out React <15.3.0 doesn't include React.PureComponent. So code like:

```
class MyClass extends React.PureComponent {
    //...
}
```

wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me I forgot `default`. So I wrote `export class MyComponent` instead of `export default class MyComponent`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a dev watch mode stop out and rebuild. I converted an ES6 module to a React Component and it only worked after a rebuild (vs a watch build).

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I tried to use `react-i18next`'s `Translation` on the parent class and the child. It was being translated twice!

Answer (score 0):

Initially i was trying **import React, {Components} from 'react';**

i didn't noticed that we have to extend only **{Component}**

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was because of importing child class into parent:

in child file:

```
class Child extends Parent {
   constructor();
}
```

in parent file:

```
import Child from 'my_path';

class Parent {
   constructor();
}
```

Problem was solved After Ive deleted child import.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem because 'react-moment'

Replace it with 'moment' library

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we were trying to extend a parent class which only had static functions. I.e.

```
Parent {
  static something() {
  }
}

Child extends Parent {
}
```

Adding a constructor to the Parent solved the issue.

```
Parent {
  constructor() {}

  static something() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add "use client" and it works for me, btw i use nextjs

Answer (score -1):

The problem, as it seems, appears to be
React.Components instead of React.Component.

Also, did you write the ReactDOM.render(, YourNode) here?

Hope you had your problem solved. Cheers!