# Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined (React.js, Flux, ES6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flux

I've been converting a simple React project from ES5 to ES6, 7 but I've run into a problem.  I get this error when I open my index.html: [image]

I've looked into some of the common fixes:

- Updating React

(15 should have full ES6 support no?)

[image]

- Misspellings in Imports or Circular Dependancies

**resultConstants.js**

```
export const RESULTS = {
  RECEIVED_SEARCH: "RECEIVED_SEARCH",
  RECEIVED_RESULTS: "RECEIVED_RESULTS"
};
```

**dispatcher.js**

```
import { Dispatcher } from 'flux';

const AppDispatcher = new Dispatcher();

export default AppDispatcher;
```

But I'm not really seeing the issue still.  Here is the store that is causing the issues.

```
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/dispatcher';
import { RESULTS } from '../constants/resultConstants';
import { FluxStore } from 'flux';

let _query = 'restaurant',
    _results = [];

const _mapOptions = {
  ...
};

class ResultStore extends FluxStore {
  query() {
    return _query;
  }

  mapOptions() {
    return _mapOptions;
  }

  all() {
    return _results.slice(0, 9);
  }

  __onDispatch(payload) {
    switch(payload.type) {
      case RESULTS.RECEIVED_SEARCH:
        _resetQuery(payload.search.query)
        _resetCenter(payload.search.center);
        resultStore.__emitChange();
        break;
      case RESULTS.RECEIVED_RESULTS:
        _resetResults(payload.results);
        resultStore.__emitChange();
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }
  }
}

function _resetQuery (query) {
  _query = query;
}

function _resetCenter (center) {
  _mapOptions.center = center;
};

function _resetResults (results) {
  _results = results;
};

export const resultStore = new ResultStore(AppDispatcher);
```

To be clear even when I include this snippet of code:

```
constructor() {
  super();
}
```

it still comes up with this error.

**Questions**

1. What are some other reasons why this error appears?
2. How is my ES6? (constructive criticism is appreciated)

Comment: Check this question for other possible problems/typos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or?rq=1

Comment: Are you sure `FluxStore` exists? If you `log` that, I bet you'll get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when extending a class from a non-existing class there's no error.
So when the super is called but there's no parent this error comes up: Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined.

Usually caused either by extending a class which you didn't quite load, either due to a typo or due to the sequence (extending class must be written below the extended class)