# I have this error : Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

When I run the code below the browser says:

**Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined**

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$uuzyb025gr28cqm0v65ka9k9' of null**

im using the latest reactjs and material ui, I have this in my package.json file :

```
"react": "^15.3.1",
"react-dom": "^15.3.1",
"react-router": "^2.7.0" 
"material-ui": "^0.15.4"
...
```

The code is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Drawer, MenuItem} from 'material-ui';
import {List, ListItem, MakeSelectable} from 'material-ui/List';
import Subheader from 'material-ui/Subheader';
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';

class Test extends React.Component {

    /**
     * Class constructor.
     */
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Render the component.
     */
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Drawer open={false} width="180px">
                    <MakeSelectable defaultValue={3}>
                    <Subheader>Selectable Contacts</Subheader>
                        <ListItem value={1} primaryText="Brendan Lim" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="/images/obenbasic.png" />}
                          nestedItems={[<ListItem value={2} primaryText="Grace Ng" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="/images/obenbasic.png" />} />,]}/>
                        <ListItem value={3} primaryText="Kerem Suer" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="/images/obenbasic.png" />}/>
                        <ListItem value={4} primaryText="Eric Hoffman" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="/images/obenbasic.png" />} />
                        <ListItem value={5} primaryText="Raquel Parrado" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="/images/obenbasic.png" />} />
                  </MakeSelectable>
               </Drawer>     
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Test;
```

Can someone help me with this issue ?

Comment: @AndrewL. No, it's `React.Component`

Comment: OP - You don't even need a constructor in this case.  Just get rid of it.

Comment: i did the following change `React.Component` to `React.component` i still have the following error : **app.js:63972 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined**

Comment: The comment that told you to use `React.component` was wrong.  Switch it back then remove your constructor.

Comment: @MichaelParker actually i need the constructor, because, im using some other stuff in there, actually the entire code is: `constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            secretData: ''
        };
    }`

Comment: Do you use `props` in your constructor?

Comment: @MichaelParker not yet, maybe later I will, why ?

Comment: Because if you needed `props` in the constructor, you'd have to pass them to `super()`.  Honestly, I'm not sure why you're having this issue.  Sorry :/

Comment: Maybe something from this post might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MakeSelectable` is a Higher Order Component. It can't be used like a component. It's taking a component as a first argument. E.g:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {List, ListItem, MakeSelectable} from 'material-ui/List';

const SelectableList = MakeSelectable(List);
```

You can have a look at https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v0.15.4/docs/src/app/components/pages/components/List/ExampleSelectable.js for a full working example.

P.S `MakeSelectable` is renamed to `makeSelectable` on the master branch for better consistency with the React community conventions.