# Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined(…)

Tags: validation, reactjs

The question that tracks this issue was not able to solve my problem.

[reactjs giving error Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or)

My react version is "^15.3.1".

I have added the code snippet below

```
import React from 'react';
import { ButtonInput } from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Form,ValidatedInput} from 'react-bootstrap-validation';

class myComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleValidSubmit = this.handleValidSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInvalidSubmit = this.handleInvalidSubmit.bind(this);

  }
  handleValidSubmit(values){

  }
  handleInvalidSubmit(errors,values){

  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Form   onValidSubmit={this.handleValidSubmit}
                onInvalidSubmit={this.handleInvalidSubmit}>

                <ValidatedInput
                    type='text'
                    label='Email'
                    name='email'
                    validate='required,isEmail'
                    errorHelp={{
                        required: 'Please enter your email',
                        isEmail: 'Email is invalid'
                    }}
                />

                <ValidatedInput
                    type='password'
                    name='password'
                    label='Password'
                    validate='required,isLength:6:60'
                    errorHelp={{
                        required: 'Please specify a password',
                        isLength: 'Password must be at least 6 characters'
                    }}
                />

                <ValidatedInput
                    type='password'
                    name='password-confirm'
                    label='Confirm Password'
                    validate={(val, context) => val === context.password}
                    errorHelp='Passwords do not match'
                />


                <ValidatedInput
                    type='checkbox'
                    name='agree'
                    label='I agree to the terms and conditions'
                    validate='isChecked'
                />

                 <ButtonInput
                    type='submit'
                    bsSize='large'
                    bsStyle='primary'
                    value='Register'
                />

            </Form>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = myComponent;
```

Comment: There is no "Form" component import

Comment: import {Form,ValidatedInput} from 'react-bootstrap-validation';

Comment: Sorry, I see now. Try to do something like console.log(ButtonInput) before your class declaration. Look like your import path is incorrect.

Comment: Also, what is `this.handleValidSubmit = this.handleValidSubmit.bind(this);`

Comment: @degr it's a common way of binding the correct `this` to the function for later use.

Comment: @degr Yeah..Its equivalent to onValidSubmit={this.handleValidSubmit.bind(this)}

Comment: can you log `React.Component`? The error is telling you that it's undefined.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella It's clean.The import issue occurs in 'react-bootstrap-validation', though I can't quite figure out what the issue is.I am using "react-bootstrap-validation": "^0.1.11" version.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's a conflict with `react-bootstrap` versions >= `0.30`.

Downgrading your `react-boostrap` version for compatibility with  `react-bootstrap-validation`may work.

The official issue thread is [here](https://github.com/heilhead/react-bootstrap-validation/issues/70). Until the authors issue an update to fix this compatibility problem, you'll probably need to downgrade your `react-bootstrap` version even if it is a suboptimal 'solution'.