# Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I am having alitle trouble with reactjs, and inheritance. This is my code setup:

```
//This is the base class, this works (File 1)
class Base extends React.Component {}
export default Base

//This is the firstchild, this also works (File 2)
class FirstChild extends Base{}     
export default FirstChild 

//This results in the above TypeError (File 3)
class SecondChild extends FirstChild{}
export default SecondChild
```

Now the strange thing is, if i change it to this:

```
class SecondChild extends Base
```

it works.

I have allready seen this post:
[reactjs giving error Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or) , but still no solution.

What i am trying to accomplish is having a base component which has some functionality, another component which is somewhat similar to the base but overrides some of the functions. And finally, a third component that builds upon the second component, but again overrides some of the functions in the first child.

For reference, i am using react: 15.4.1

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is recommended to prefer composition over inheritance : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html
Maybe you could try to change it that way.

Comment: That means you didn't properly import `FirstChild`, as it is undefined when the `SecondChild` class is getting defined. Show us the full files.

Comment: Secondchild is only "import FirstChild from '..'. and class SecondChild extends Firstchild". I also thought there was something wrong with the import, but when i do console.log(FirstChild ) from the SecondChild constructor, i do get the class in the console

Comment: This sometimes happens if you have circular dependencies, hard to say without a reproducible example though.