# ReactJS - Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've been following along a course on udemy, but there's an error that keeps showing up no matter what I do:

[image]

Here's the components code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Chart from '../components/chart';


class WeatherList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderWeather(cityData) {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    weather: state.weather
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```

Here's the Chart component that I'm importing:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Sparklines, SparklinesLine, SparklinesReferenceLine } from 'react-sparklines';
import _ from 'lodash';


function average(data) {
  return _.round(_.sum(data) / data.length);
}

const Chart = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Sparklines width={80} height={80} data={thisprops.data}>
        <SparklinesLine color={props.color} />
        <SparklinesReferenceLine type="avg" />
      </Sparklines>
      <div>
        { average(props.data) } { props.units }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Chart;
```

But apparently React.Component is undefined so it throws an error.

Comment: Try to remove your constructor please. According to reactjs doc "If you don't initialize state and you don't bind methods, you don't need to implement a constructor for your React component."

Comment: GabrielDiez It still throws the same error, I only added the constructor earlier to see if it does anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reactjs giving error Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or)

Comment: is `Chart` file name realy lower case `chart`?

Comment: yes it is, the error isn't related to modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. The bug is due to  'react-sparklines'  . Downgrade the version  by:

`npm i --save react-sparklines@1.6.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further inspection, it looks like the problem is in your `Chart` component as you're trying to access an undefined `thisprops` object in the component.

So, instead of `data={thisprops.data}`, it should be: `data={props.data}`.

Comment: My react version is @0.14.9 and it ran everything perfectly until I added the Chart component, as for the code, it doesn't really matter because when I comment out the `import Chart from 'url'` it doesn't throw the error. So i'm only showing the piece that broke the app.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try exporting your Chart with a named `default` export instead of exporting just a function. Also, why don't you post entire `Chart` component code since it was the one that caused the issue?

Comment: I've just added the rest of the file in the question

Comment: What about this - `data={thisprops.data}`? It should be `data={props.data}`, obviously. I updated my answer as a solution to this issue.

Comment: That's only there because I tried to turn it into a class based component and then it didn't do anything, so that's an unrelated issue. I'm still having the same problem.Thank you for trying but I think this problem just has no solution. I'm gonna close it very soon