# React.Component and React.PureComponent show different behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am adding runnable code snippets below. see the difference 
 First one is React.PureComponent version

```js
class App extends React.PureComponent {
 
  render() {
    console.log('re-render')
    return (
    <div>
     <span>I am parent</span>
     {this.props.children}
    </div>
    )
  }
}

  ReactDOM.render(
    <App>
      <div>
        I am the child
      </div>
    </App>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  )


//setTimeout(render, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Second one is React.Component version

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    console.log('re-render')
    return (
    <div>
     <span>I am parent</span>
     {this.props.children}
    </div>
    )
  }
}

  ReactDOM.render(
    <App>
      <div>
        I am the child
      </div>
    </App>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  )


//setTimeout(render, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Why the second one runs successfully, but not the first one?? I tried exploring for the reason, but didnot find any good reason

Comment: I just tried your first code in jsfiddle and it works :(

Comment: which  version of react ar you using , my fiddle has 15.1.0 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I don't think `React.PureComponent` exists in version `15.1.0`.

The error you get (`"Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined"`) is usually triggered by a typo, or by extending a class that doesn't exist (see more details in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or)).

My suggestion is to keep your 3rd party libs up to date and use the latest version of React in this case.

Here's your own example after the react upgrade:

```js
class App extends React.PureComponent {
 
  render() {
    console.log('re-render')
    return (
    <div>
     <span>I am parent</span>
     {this.props.children}
    </div>
    )
  }
}

  ReactDOM.render(
    <App>
      <div>
        I am the child
      </div>
    </App>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  )


//setTimeout(render, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, PureComponent was introduced in React 15.3

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

React.PureComponent is added after 15.3.0 version because of which there is a error in first case. 
If you want your first case to work please check the snippet. I have updated the react version.

```js
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log('re-render')
    return (
    <div>
     <span>I am parent</span>
     {this.props.children}
    </div>
    )
  }
}

  ReactDOM.render(
    <App>
      <div>
        I am the child
      </div>
    </App>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  )


//setTimeout(render, 1000)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

For reference please check 
[react-release-version](https://github.com/facebook/react/releases?after=v15.3.2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

React.PureComponent will not work in your case because you are using a older version of ReactJS. Actually the support for React.PureComponent was introduced with React 15.3 on June 29, 2016.