# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: reactjs, antd

Below is my loginForm.js from where I suspect the error is originating:-

```
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';
const FormItem = Form.Item;
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class NormalLoginForm extends Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Username" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
          })(
            <Input prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" className="login-form-button">
            Log in
          </Button>
          Or <a href="">register now!</a>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create()(NormalLoginForm);

export default WrappedNormalLoginForm;
```

Below is my main component file where I load handle routing:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import WrappedNormalLoginForm from './loginForm'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="container">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
              <Route exact path="/" component={WrappedNormalLoginForm} />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am unable to resolve this issue. I have extended using capital C which was mentioned as a fix for many of the questions asked regarding this.

Comment: try to comment out stuffs, make it simpler.This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: constructor is missing add constructor with super()