# React JS routing not working (Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am developing a simple web application using React JS. I just started using React JS a few days ago. Now working on the routing part following a tutorial. But my code is not working.

This is my entry js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import ListComponent from './list.component';
import AddItemComponent from './additem.component';
import AboutComponent from './about.component';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';


//Create
class TodoComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()

        this.state = { todos : [ "Wash up", "Eat some KFC", "Take a long nap" ], age: 30 }
    }

    render(){
        var ager = setTimeout(()=> {
            this.setState({ age: this.state.age + 3 })
        }, 3000)

        return (
            <div>
                <h4>Age: {this.state.age}</h4>
                <ListComponent todos={this.state.todos} />
                <div>
                <AddItemComponent />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



//put component into HTML page.
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={TodoComponent} />
        <Route path="/" component={AboutComponent} />
    </Router>
    , 
    document.getElementById('todo-wrapper'));
```

Other components are in the individual module file and they have no error. I already tested them all before implementing route feature. When I run my code, I got this error in the browser console.

```
bundle.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object
    at bundle.js:6
    at bundle.js:6
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:6)
    at S (bundle.js:1)
    at r (bundle.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:22)
    at S (bundle.js:1)
    at r (bundle.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:22)
    at S (bundle.js:1)
```

What is missing or wrong with my code? Why it is not working?

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "realproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --port 1234 --history-api-fallback"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.13.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: you may find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or

Comment: Hi, I looked at the answer before as well. After hours of a headache, I found out that AboutComponent is extending from React, not React.Component. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**First of all**, `render` should always remain pure. It's a very bad practice to do side-effecty things in there, and calling `setState` is a big red flag.

**Second** `browserHistory` isn't the thing in version 4, so you can remove that, you're importing everything from `react-router` it should `react-router-dom`

**Third**, `react-router-dom` doesn't export a `Router`, instead, it exports a `BrowserRouter` so you need to  `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'`

You must decide which component will take the main page you can't have two Router's with the same path as you did `'/'` as well you to avoid any problems add `exact` only to the main path

```
 <Router>
        <Route path="/" exact component={TodoComponent} />
        <Route path="/about" component={AboutComponent} />
    </Router>
```

**To fix that error** `ReactDom` should match the case in your import, so it should be `ReactDOM`

Instead of this code

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
```

Should be

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

As well make sure all your class components like this `React.Component` with an uppercase `C`

Comment: @WaiYanHein Hi, answer edited it should fix the error

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `props` as parameter: `constructor(props)` and `super(props)`.