# "Syntax error: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module" when using react-share package

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have been through many threads to solve this issue but unfortunately non of them is working.
I am trying to import react-share like this

```
    import {
    FacebookShareButton,
    GooglePlusShareButton,
    TwitterShareButton,
    WhatsappShareButton,

    FacebookIcon,
    TwitterIcon,
    WhatsappIcon

} from 'react-share';

"use strict";

require('./../../../assets/styles/components/thread.less');


//var reactShare = require('react-share');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Fluxxor = require('fluxxor');
var _ = require("lodash");

var FluxMixin = Fluxxor.FluxMixin(React);
var StoreWatchMixin = Fluxxor.StoreWatchMixin;
```

But i am receiving the error of

```
syntaxerro: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

I have installed babel and have performed all the suggestions given in threads but not been able to solve the issue

For the reference my webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    devtool: 'hidden-source-map',
    entry: {
        microaudio: "./reactFrontend/js/main",
        notsupported: "./reactFrontend/js/notsupported",
        sharerender: "./reactFrontend/js/shareRender",
        privacyDeclaration: "./reactFrontend/js/privacyDeclaration",
        legal: "./reactFrontend/js/legal"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "frontend/",
        filename: "[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "[chunkhash].js"
    },
    node: {
        fs: "empty"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: "jsx-loader?insertPragma=React.DOM&harmony"
        }, {
            test: /\.json/,
            loader: "json-loader"
        }, {
            test: /\.less/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader?{browsers:['last 3 versions', 'Android >= 4', 'safari >= 4']}!less-loader"
        }, {
            test: /\.tpl/,
            loader: "ejs-loader"
        }, {
            test: /\.woff(\?\S*)?$/,
            loader: "url-loader?prefix=/font&limit=1000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
        }, {
            test: /\.woff2(\?\S*)?$/,
            loader: "url-loader?prefix=/font&limit=1000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
        }, {
            test: /\.ttf(\?\S*)?$/,
            loader: "file-loader?prefix=/font"
        }, {
            test: /\.eot(\?\S*)?$/,
            loader: "file-loader?prefix=/font"
        }, {
            test: /\.svg(\?\S*)?$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=1000000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
        }, {
            test: /\.png$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png"
        }, {
            test: /\.gif$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif"
        }, {
            test: /\.jpg$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpeg"
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        //setup momentjs context to only include languages we do need!
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /de|en/)
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js", ".jsx"],
        alias: {
            av: __dirname + "/reactFrontend/js/vendors/aurora/aurora",
            "ogg.js": __dirname + "/reactFrontend/js/vendors/aurora/ogg",
            "vorbis.js": __dirname + "/reactFrontend/js/vendors/aurora/vorbis"
        }
    },

    babel: {
    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0'],
    plugins: ['transform-runtime']
  }
};
```

and my package.json file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "audiyoh-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/js/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "test-martin-local": "SET NODE_ENV=development&& SET NODE_APP_INSTANCE=martin&& gulp test-bs",
    "test-robert-local": "SET NODE_ENV=development&& SET NODE_APP_INSTANCE=robert&& gulp test-bs",
    "wds": "webpack-dev-server --https --inline --hot --color --history-api-fallback"
  },
  "author": "atroo GbR",
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Martin Foerster",
      "email": "martin@atroo.de"
    },
    {
      "name": "Robert Krüger",
      "email": "robert@atroo.de"
    }
  ],
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "blanket": "^1.1.6",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "0.0.3",
    "chai": "^3.3.0",
    "coveralls": "^2.11.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "ejs-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "glob": "^4.3.5",
    "gulp": "^3.8.6",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-mocha": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-spawn-mocha": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.0",
    "i18next-resource-store-loader": "0.0.2",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.12.2",
    "less": "^2.2.0",
    "less-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "mocha": "^2.1.0",
    "mocha-lcov-reporter": "^0.0.1",
    "node-notifier": "^4.4.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^2.47.0",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.8.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "wasm-loader": "1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.0.1",
    "worker-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "yargs": "^3.26.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "av": "^0.4.9",
    "backbone": "^1.1.2",
    "backbone.wreqr": "^1.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.2",
    "color": "^0.11.3",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.2-5",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "flux": "^2.0.0",
    "fluxxor": "^1.7.3",
    "get-user-media-promise": "^1.1.1",
    "i18next-client": "^1.7.7",
    "jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "keymirror": "~0.1.0",
    "less-to-json-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^3.8.0",
    "modernizr": "^3.3.1",
    "modernizr-loader": "0.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.9.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.2",
    "normalize.css": "^3.0.2",
    "object-assign": "^1.0.0",
    "ogg.js": "^0.1.0",
    "promise": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "^0.14.5",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.21.2",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.5",
    "react-router": "^2.3.0",
    "react-tools": "^0.12.2",
    "scriptjs": "^2.5.8",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.4.5",
    "tunajs": "^0.4.5",
    "velocity-animate": "^1.2.1",
    "vorbis.js": "^0.1.1",
    "web-audio-daw": "^2.3.1"
  }
}
```

i created a .babelrc file as well (manually in the root where webpack.config.js is)

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
}
```

I am new in ReactJs so i am not having a good grasp on the requirements of such. Please help! Thanks

Comment: First of all: I don't see needs to mix `import` and `require` statements here.
As I can see your import are already at the top of the file... maybe is your "use strict" line that lead to the issue? You can remove it...
Finally, please share the whole traceback you get, are you sure that the issue came from the `react-share` import?

Comment: It doesnt come particularly when using react-share i just referred it; I am using someones code and they have used require so i havent changed it. I tried to use require too but then i get another error which states "Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined"

Comment: I tired removing "use strict" still throws same error. i have already discussed about Super Expression in different thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270112/react-share-throws-error-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or-a-f?noredirect=1#comment91487547_52270112 havent got any response on it

Answer (score 0):

[jsx-loader has been deprecated for at least 3 years.](https://github.com/petehunt/jsx-loader)

You'll want to actually use `babel-loader` for JSX files if you need `import`s and other ES6 syntax implemented in the last three years to work.

Comment: "babel-loader": "^8.0.2"  is loaded check the package.json

Comment: It's not in use in your webpack.config.js.