# Javascript error only happens when uglify mangle is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs

This javascript error

> Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Is only thrown when webpack `mode` is set to `production`, which I've narrowed down to UglifyJsPlugin > uglifyOptions > compress.

Has anybody experienced this issue? Or have a suggestion on where to look?

Comment: The big difference is that the devDependencies will not be included in the production build.  Try looking through the dev dependencies and ensuring that those are not needed for production builds.

Comment: Did you see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or ? Be aware of circular dependencies, or using React.component instead of React.Component

Comment: Yes, but I'm pretty sure this issue is not a circular reference if it's only present when Uglify compress is set to true

Comment: Have you reduced this down to a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

It helped me:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/264#issuecomment-393727878

```js
new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          compress: {
            inline: false,
          },
        },
      }),
```