# react-redux with webpack giving error Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am getting a blank browser and in console I get this error of

> Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a
>   function, not undefined

I have read other similar posts but did not see anything relevant.

This is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "JSFaddle",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:ldco2016/JSFaddle.git",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-standalone": "^6.7.7",
    "esprima": "^2.7.2",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-addons-create-fragment": "^15.1.0",
    "react-codemirror": "^0.2.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "react-split-pane": "^0.1.42",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "reselect": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

This is the `src/index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';
import Globals from './globals';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.render'));
```

You have noticed I am running some older versions of webpack and other packages as I am trying to get up to speed with Webpack, but I am not sure if that is the problem. I am not sure what its referencing.

I was asked about extending and I am doing so here in `src/components/App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SplitPane from 'react-split-pane';
import Editor from './editor';
import Viewer from './viewer';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const width = window.innerHeight;

    return (
      <SplitPane split="vertical" defaultSize={width}>
        <Editor />
        <Viewer />
      </SplitPane>
    );
  }
}
```

To be clear that I have thoroughly reviewed other posts regarding this error, here are my component files.

Editor.js:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CodeMirror from 'react-codemirror';
import 'codemirror/mode/jsx/jsx';
import * as actions from 'actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Editor extends Component {
  onCodeChange(code) {
    this.props.updateCode(code);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CodeMirror
          value={this.props.code}
          onChange={this.onCodeChange.bind(this)}
          options={{ mode: 'jsx', lineNumbers: true, tabSize: 2 }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({code}) {
  return { code };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Editor);
```

Viewer.js:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import parseExpressions from 'selectors/parse_expressions';
import SplitPane from 'react-split-pane';

class Viewer extends Component {
  evaluateExpressions(expressions) {
    const formattedExpressions = _.mapValues(expressions, expression => {
      const result = eval(expression);

      if (result && result.type) {
        return result;
      } else if (_.isFunction(result) && result.name) {
        return <i>Function {result.name}</i>;
      } else if (_.isBoolean(result)) {
        return result ? 'True' : 'False';
      } else if (_.isObject(result) || _.isArray(result)) {
        return JSON.stringify(result);
      }

      return result;
    });

    return _.map(formattedExpressions, (expression, line) =>
      <div>{expression}</div>
    );
  }

  renderExpressions(code) {
    return this.evaluateExpressions(this.props.expressions);
  }

  render() {
    const defaultHeight = window.innerHeight / 1.3;

    return (
      <SplitPane split="horizontal" defaultSize={defaultHeight} className="viewer">
        <div className="result">
          {this.renderExpressions(this.props.code)}
        </div>
        <div className="errors">
          {this.props.errors}
        </div>
      </SplitPane>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  let expressions, errors;

  try {
    expressions = parseExpressions(state);
  } catch (e) {
    errors = e.toString();
  }

  return { expressions, errors };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Viewer);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35656593/5812047

Comment: @SamVK, I have added my components file, the only files that would contain `class`-based components and you will see it is not relevant to the other posts with same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lengthy process of elimination, I decided to try to just upgrade from `react` and `react-dom` version `0.14.x` to `15.4.0` and I restarted the application via `npm start` and it works now.