# Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined - Reactjs Runtime Error

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting runtime error in react js **"Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined"**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import { TransmittalForm, DocumentCart } from '../components';


class TransmittalsForm extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        items: []
    };

    this.parentOnChange = this.parentOnChange.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.state.items = [];
}

parentOnChange(docItems) {
    this.setState({
        items: docItems
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="transmittals">
            <TransmittalForm docItems={this.state.items} />
            <DocumentCart docItemsChange={this.parentOnChange} />
        </div>
    );
  }
 }

 render(
  <TransmittalsForm />,
  document.getElementById('people-table')
 );
```

I'm using react v15.2.0. and not seeing any error while npm run build.

Comment: I think you need to show the code of `TransmittalForm` and `DocumentCart` components code too because there is no error in current code.

Comment: Have you seen this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or