# To Save the items Onpress of flatlist items in react native

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-flatlist

I'm new to react native. I want to save the items of `flatlist` when i press the `flatlist` items, and display it.
I have first implemented the Autocomplete view from which i'm selecting the countries and then display the data in `flatlist`.

```
render() {
const { query } = this.state;
const autotime = this.findtimezone(query);
const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <Autocomplete
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
      data={autotime.length === 1 && comp(query, autotime[0].name) ? [] : autotime}
      defaultValue={this.state.timeZone}
      onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
      placeholder="Enter Location"
      renderItem={({ name, release_date }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: name,timezoneArray:autotime[0].timezones })}>
          <Text style={styles.itemText}>
            {name}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />
    <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
    {autotime.length > 0 ? (
      <FlatList
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      style={{flex:1}}
      data={this.state.timezoneArray}
      renderItem={({item,index}) => <Text style={{padding:10,borderBottomWidth:1,borderBottomColor:"#000000"}}>{item}</Text>}


      />

      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.infoText}>Enter Location</Text>
      )}
    </View>    

  </View>
 );
```

I want to that when i click on the `flatlist` item it saves the item through async, and display it in `flatlist`.

Comment: please provide only relevant code so that we can understand what you want..

Comment: instead of rendering text create a component which has a button and takes text prop. `renderItem={({item,index}) => <MyComponent style={{padding:10,borderBottomWidth:1,borderBottomColor:"#000000"}} text={text}>{item} />}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a component that will be rendered by the Flatlist and in that component add a text and button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class TimeZoneItem extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    text: '',
    onPress: () => {},
  };

  render() {
    const { text, onPress } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.timeZoneItem}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{text}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.save}>Save</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 12,
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    padding: 12,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  timeZoneItem: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  textStyle: {
    flex: 3,
  },
  save: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

Use it in your Flatlist like this

```
{ autotime.length > 0 ? (
    <FlatList
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      data={this.state.timezoneArray}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <TimeZoneItem text={item} />
      )}
    />
  ) : (
    <Text style={styles.infoText}>Enter Location</Text>
  );
}
```

Demo

[image: flatlist component]

[Working Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/save-flatlist-items-in-a-different-flatlist)

Comment: Thanks, But i How can i pass TimeZoneItem class .

Comment: In the flatlist renderItem

Comment: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: View config not found for name timezoneitem. Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

Comment: i have implemented this code           renderItem={({ item }) => <timezoneitem text={item} />}

Comment: the error tells you where the problem is, your component needs to start with a capital letter

Comment: `renderItem={({ item }) => <timezoneitem text={item} />}` should be `renderItem={({ item }) => <TimeZoneItem text={item} />}` with capital `T` for  `TimeZoneItem`

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TimeZoneItem

Comment: Did you import TimeZoneItem? `import TimeZoneItem from './TimeZoneItem';` do you know how to import a component?

Comment: do you see where the error is rom your import? `TimeZoneItem` not `Timezoneitem` check the casing of the `Timezoneitem`

Comment: i want to display the saved item in a seprate flatlist.

Comment: and remove it from the current flatlist?

Comment: I want to display the saved timezones when i click on save button it displayes the timezones in a separate flatlist

Comment: But i want to display the saved item in a seprate flatlist on separate class

Comment: Super expression must either be null or a function.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or

Comment: I implemented whatever is present in link now my application is crashing.