# multiple react components and hierarchy in using them, gives issues on the higher level

Tags: webpack

I have many React components done by me.
Comp 1 is loading properly. No issue at all.
Comp 2 uses comp 1 and is loading properly. No issue at all.

My main app uses Comp 2, and Comp 2 is using Comp 1.
I get error.
The error is misleading in the begging.

Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

The error is inside my Comp 2!

It looks like I have looping in dependency! But I have no idea how this needs to be fixed!

Anyone can help?

Tried making the npm packages same. react-bootstrap looked like making trouble. But now all of them are same version.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Working with react sometimes gets little tricky, personally, I strongly recommend draw out your app component hierarchy, then map out how the data flow is happening in your application. Once you get a clear idea where the data is passing through, and how it's easy to find out where the bug is specifically. 
check this link as well

[reactjs giving error Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or)