# what's the problem with the "super" method?

Tags: react-native

This is my code:

```
import React, { component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

class GuideLine extends component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    };
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
              <Text>Hello</Text>

            </View>
        );
    };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default GuideLine;
```

and I'm getting this error : Super expression must either be null or function. What should I do to fix it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reactjs giving error Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or)

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Are you sure about extending component and not Component?

Comment: I changed that. But the error still remains.

Comment: It's definitely what @Konstantin said. Can you update your code with that change, and maybe a screenshot of the error?