# Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function - It won't go away

Tags: reactjs

I get error saying:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at index.js:974:1
    at index.js:973:1
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:972:1)
    at n (index.js:14:1)
    at e.exports (index.js:50:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:4:1)
    at f ((index):1:1398)
    at Module.79 (change-password.js:26:15)
    at f ((index):1:1398)
    at Object.46 (main.96136933.chunk.js:1:87)
```

Here is my index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { HashRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import AccountDetails from "./components/admin/account-details";
import AddDeveloper from "./components/admin/add-developer";
import AddProperty from "./components/admin/add-property";
import Address from "./components/admin/adress";
import ChangePassword from "./components/admin/change-password";
// import Dashboard from "./components/admin/dashboard";
// import EditDeveloper from "./components/admin/edit-developer";
// import FavouriteProperties from "./components/admin/favourite-properties";
import ListDeveloper from "./components/admin/list-developer";
import ListProperty from "./components/admin/list-property";
import Payment from "./components/admin/payment";
import Profile from "./components/admin/profile";
import FreeholdGridPage from "./components/freehold";
import HomeV1 from "./components/home-v1";
import LoginV1 from "./components/login";
import MyAccount from "./components/my-account";
import PersistLogin from "./components/persistLogin";
import RegisterV1 from "./components/register";
import RequireAuth from "./components/require-Auth";
import Service from "./components/service";
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthProvider";

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <AuthProvider>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<HomeV1 />} />
              <Route path="/login" element={<LoginV1 />} />
              <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterV1 />} />
              <Route path="/freehold" element={<FreeholdGridPage />} />
              <Route element={<PersistLogin />}>
                <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
                  <Route path="/service" element={<Service />} />
                  <Route path="/my-account" element={<MyAccount />}>
                    {/* <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} /> */}
                    <Route path="profiles" element={<Profile />} />
                    <Route path="address" element={<Address />} />
                    <Route
                      path="account-details"
                      element={<AccountDetails />}
                    />
                    <Route path="dev/list" element={<ListDeveloper />} />
                    <Route path="prop/list" element={<ListProperty />} />
                    {/* <Route path="fav-prop" element={<FavouriteProperties />} /> */}
                    <Route path="dev/add" element={<AddDeveloper />} />
                    <Route path="prop/add" element={<AddProperty />} />
                    <Route path="payments" element={<Payment />} />
                    <Route
                      path="change-password"
                      element={<ChangePassword />}
                    />
                    {/* <Route path="dev/edit/:id" element={<EditDeveloper />} />
                    <Route path="prop/edit/:id" element={<EditDeveloper />} /> */}
                  </Route>
                  {/* <Route path="/service-details" element={<ServiceDetails />} />
                  <Route path="/team" element={<Team />} />
                  <Route path="/add-listing" element={<AddListing />} /> */}
                </Route>
              </Route>
            </Routes>
          </AuthProvider>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default Root;

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById("quarter"));
```

Here is my changepassword.js

```js
import React from "react";

function ChangePassword() {
  return (
    <div className="tab-pane " id="ltn_tab_1_9">
      <div className="ltn__myaccount-tab-content-inner">
        <div className="account-login-inner">
          <form action="#" className="ltn__form-box contact-form-box">
            <h5 className="mb-30">Change Password</h5>
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Current Password*"
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="New Password*"
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Confirm New Password*"
            />
            <div className="btn-wrapper mt-0">
              <button className="theme-btn-1 btn btn-block" type="submit">
                Save Changes
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChangePassword;
```

I am struggling on it for a whole day. Can you please help me? I have tried all of the possible solutions but still could not come to fix this issue. The other posts say this about importing the wrong component but I feel everything is good here.

Answer (score -1):

You can put this line in your first file:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
```

for more information read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or).