# Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function (JavaScript/TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class A which extends a class B, that extends another class C. Whenever I try to create a new instance of class A within an arbitrary function, I get this error: ***Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function***

example:

***A.ts***

```
import {B} from "./B.ts";

export class A extends B {

}
```

***B.ts***

```
import {C} from "./C.ts";

export class B extends C {

}
```

***C.ts***

```
export class C {

}
```

Else Where within my application

***functions.ts***

```
import {A} from "./A.ts";

export function doSomething(){
     const a = new A(); // throws Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
}
```

By the way, I have already reviewed [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or) along with others, but none of the answers attributes to my case.

Comment: @devpolo  Unfortunately the answer you provided wasn't the solution to my problem. I already tried the solution you offered earlier before posting the problem here. I just didn't mention all the work arounds I have tried, because I didn't want  the question to be bulky. However, I have provided what worked for me as a comment below your answer, since it isn't an exact solution. But, I'm guessing it's something that has to do with the babel-loader version in use by the webpack version (5.60.0) I'm using for my project. I didn't want to go through the hassle of opening issues on git.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your research, it looks like you are trying to find a solution in the `react` ecosystem but it's currently a `javascript` question.

In order to be able to instantiate a `class`, you must add `super` to access extended `class` properties:

```js
import { B } from "./B.ts";

export class A extends B {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
```

More infos on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)

Comment: The reason why I posted the link to the react question, was because that was the suggested link I got when I searched for the answer on SO, before posting my own issue. I wasn't getting anything related to my problem. Thanks for the answer anyways. But your answer wasn't the solution to my problem. I already tried that, but with the same result. In the end, since I couldn't figure out a solution to the problem, I shelved the idea of using the instantiated variable within the functions.ts file.