# iframe causing a lot of cookies issues

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to embed a video on my NextJS website by using `<iframe`. The problem is it causes a lot of cookies issues in Chrome browser. Plus the performance dropped significantly.

```
<iframe
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r9jwGansp1E"
  allowFullScreen
></iframe>
```

[image]

I also tried to use [aspect-ratio plugin](https://www.themes.dev/blog/easily-embed-responsive-youtube-video-with-tailwind-css/) but I got the same issues and the page was rendered blank.

```
<div className="aspect-w-16 aspect-h-9">
  <iframe
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r9jwGansp1E"
    allowFullScreen
  ></iframe>
</div>
```

The question is am I doing it right? Or another way should be used to embed a video and avoid issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you won't be able to solve this warning, because you cannot set the sameSite attribute as youtube is a third-party service.

If you have this issue in your local environment don't worry, it should be gone when you deploy to a production server with HTTPS, it probably has something to do with the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use a library such as [react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) to embed videos instead of using iframes, as iframes can sometimes result in cross-origin issues.

Comment: when I use this library following the instruction, I'm getting `TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function`

Comment: @JohnPix Longshot here, but if you are using class components you should do `React.Component` instead of `React.component`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into YouTube iframe player API.
There is a really good sample on this page:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

There is a resolution inside the very error.

Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:

- Specify `SameSite=none` and `Secure` if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-party use
- Specify `SameSite=Strict` or `SameSite=Lax` if the cookie should not be sent in cross-site requests.

Youtube.com has a **ton** of cookies. That is why you are recieving such an amount of errors.

#### Try to read the complete error next time ;)