# Error after Realm installation "Super expression must be null or a function" in React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, realm

I'm trying to install Realm in my React Native project. I have done everything and created another file for creating the context in Realm. Here's the realm context file:

```js
import {Realm} from '@realm/react';
import {createRealmContext} from '@realm/react';

class Movie extends Realm.Object<Movie> {
  description!: string;
  title!:string;
  releaseyear!: number; 
  userId!: string;
  constructor(realm: Realm, description: string, title:string, releaseyear: number, userId?: string) {
    super(realm, {description, title, releaseyear, userId: userId || '_SYNC_DISABLED_'});
  }  
}


const realmContext = createRealmContext({
  schema: [Movie]  
});

export default realmContext
```

After this, i'm just wrapping the context provider in `App.js` like this:

```js
import {realmContext} from  "./src/hooks/Realm";


const App = observer(() => {
  const scheme = useColorScheme();
  const isDarkMode = scheme === "dark";
  const {RealmProvider} = realmContext  // this is line from where the error is coming 

  React.useEffect(() => {
    StatusBar.setBarStyle(isDarkMode ? "light-content" : "dark-content");
    if (isAndroid) {
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor("rgba(0,0,0,0)");
      StatusBar.setTranslucent(true);
    }
  }, [scheme, isDarkMode]);

 
  return (
    <>
      <RealmProvider>
        <Navigation />
      </RealmProvider>
   
    </>
  );
});

export default App;
```

Now where am i going wrong. I am getting the error `"Super expression must be null or a function"`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116430/reactjs-giving-error-uncaught-typeerror-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or). It's a good idea to do a bit of research before posting questions as it may have been answered previously - see [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Super+expression+must+be+null+or+a+function)